# Calling al.exe from batch file during post build event

Tags: visual-studio-2008, build-automation

I have a batch file which I would like to call in a post build event in VS 2008. This contains calls to `al.exe`. The build of said project usually fails with `exit code 1`.

If, in the batch file, I replace the call to `al.exe` with a call to `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\al.exe`, the build event is processed as desired. This means that in the post build event 'al.exe' is not found during execution of the batch file.

The problem is that I need to have this executed on our build server, not just on my machine, and in the long run there will be more than just on build server, so I'd prefer to not refer to hard coded pathnames.

I came across environment variables `$(MSBuildBinPath)` and `$(MSBuildToolsPath)` but they are not listed as macros in the post build event editor and do not seem to solve the problem, when I use them in the batch file like this:

```
"$(MSBuildToolsPath)\al.exe" /link: ...
```

Maybe the syntax (double quotes) is incorrect here? Of course I already tried several variations. If not: does anyone have any other hint how to get around using the hard coded path string? I did found postings here which suggest installing updated versions of MS tools, but the setup of the build servers is not under my control and rather standardized, so changing this there would be a rather painful task. For this reason I'd prefer a solution which I can control from within the VS 2008 project setup.

The batch file is the output of running the binary produced by another project which is build earlier, so I could write the correct (machine dependent) path into the batch file, if I only knew how to figure out the path either in that other project or at runtime of the binary which is output by that project.

TIA, Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What tool(s) are you using to automate your build?

From my experience, I would not recommend adding things like this directly to the project file.  It becomes a maintenance nightmare if you do these kinds of things in multiple project files and then need to change how your build works.

Piggybacking off what @Attila suggested, I would say create a simple MSBuild file to execute that would handle the build and then execute my batch file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectsToBuild Include="MyCoolProject.csproj; MyCoolSolution.sln" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="Build">
    <MSBuild Projects="@(ProjectsToBuild)" />
    <Exec Command="MyBatchFile.bat $(MSBuildToolsPath)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Then instead of having your build server execute the build on your project or solution file, execute MSBuild on the file above.

```
MSBuild.exe CoolProjectBuildFile.Build
```

Hope this helps!  Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hi Tyson, thanks for the suggestion. I'm not sure I understand it correctly, though. I'm using VS 2008 Professional, which create XML files (.csproj) which kind of look like the one you suggested. The after and before build events are XML sections within a <PropertyGroup> in the file. So it is my understanding that I'm already kind of doing what you are suggesting (without being aware of it till now) is that correct? Actually I'm not doing this in mutliple project files, but there is one project which is dedicated to just doing this.

Comment: Yes and no :-)  With the release of DotNET 2.0 (and VS2005) all .csproj files are actually MSBuild files.  Basically what I was suggesting was to create a wrapper around the process of compiling and executing your .bat file instead of including directly in the .csproj file (my personal preference)   You can also take the <Exec /> line from my sample above and put it directly in the "AfterBuild" target of your .csproj file.  Just take and edit it directly using a text editor.

Answer (score 1):

You could try passing the `MSBuildToolsPath` to the batch file as parameter when you invoke the script (at post-build) and use `%1` for the path to `al.exe`.